# Invoking Printer directely by URL using BIRT Reporting and JBOSS

Tags: java, printing, jboss, birt

Hello Every body,

i deployed the birt runtime on jboss as 7.1 and i am just trying to invoke a report by a simple url invocation

this is work perfectely when i  made :

http://127.0.0.1:8080/birt/frameset?__report=myreport.rptdesign&__format=PDF

but when i add

__action=print

I obtain an error : no printer

i suppose that i have to put an other url parameter called "PRINTER", could you please help me to know how exactely i have to put in __PRINTER parameter

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ampersand & before the double underline that starts the next parameter.

Your link would be
http://127.0.0.1:8080/birt/frameset?__report=myreport.rptdesign&__format=PDF&__action=print

I have never tried to print via a link, but I have used multiple parameters in a link, you may also have other issues, but this is the first one.